# Vue.js: Show/Hide buttons on navbar based on Vuex Store state when the user is logged in or not

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, vuex, vue-cli-3

I'm creating a navbar that shows or hides buttons depending if the user is logged in or not.
For that, I'm saving the state on Vuex and localStorage.

I'm trying to build a dynamic menu, using a list of objects (i.e. `rightMenu`) that contains the information of the buttons (i.e. route, title and a flag that indicates if the button may show or not if the user is logged in).

Always that the user logs in the system, the `this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn` changes to `true`, however the template does not change, the button stays in the same initial state when the user was not logged in.
For example: the `sign out` button does not show when `this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn` updates.
But when I click 'ctrl+F5' and the page reloads, the buttons show correctly.
In this case, for example, the `sign out` button appears correctly when I reload the page manually.

I'm thinking in to force the page to reload again when the user logs in or logs out, however I believe that it is not a good option.

Could anyone help me?

I'm giving the code that I'm using below.

Thank you in advance.

**Menu.vue > template**

```html
<div>
    <v-toolbar color='grey darken-3' dark>
        <v-toolbar-title>Site</v-toolbar-title>

        ...

        <v-toolbar-items class='hidden-sm-and-down'>
            <v-btn v-for='item in rightMenu' :key='item.title'
                   :to='item.to' v-if='item.showButton' flat>
                   {{ item.title }}
            </v-btn>
        </v-toolbar-items>

    </v-toolbar>

    <router-view/>
</div>
```

**Menu.vue > script**

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      rightMenu: [
        { to: '/sign_in', title: 'sign in'
          showButton: !this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn },
        { to: '/sign_up', title: 'sign up'
          showButton: !this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn },
        { to: '/sign_out', title: 'sign out'
          showButton: this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn }
      ]
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

**store.js**

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    auth: {
      token: '',
      isUserLoggedIn: false
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setAuthToken (state, token) {  // I use it on the Login
      state.auth.token = token
      state.auth.isUserLoggedIn = !!token
      localStorage.setItem('store', JSON.stringify(state))
    },
    cleanAuth (state) {  // I use it on the Logout
      state.auth = {
        token: '',
        isUserLoggedIn: false
      }
      localStorage.setItem('store', JSON.stringify(state))
    }
  }
  ...
})
```

**EDIT 1:**

When I use `this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn` explicitly on my code, it works well. So, the button appears and disappears correctly. I give below an example:

**Menu.vue > template**

```html
<v-toolbar-items class='hidden-sm-and-down'>
    <v-btn v-if='this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn' flat> 
      Test {{ this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn }}
    </v-btn>
</v-toolbar-items>
```

Hence, I believe that the problem is in the binding of `showButton` with `this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn`.

Comment: instead of accessing properties from store like you currently have, it might be better to map it to a computed variable and work with that.

Comment: Thank you Chris Li, with your tip I was able to fix my problem and I've written an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the answers of Chris Li, Andrei Gheorghiu and Sajib Khan I could solve my problem.

Andrei Gheorghiu have explained that I can't access computed properties in `data()` and Chris Li suggested that I use a computed variable instead. These answers plus Sajib Khan example I was able to think in a solution that I share below. I hope that it help others in the future.

In a nutshell, I've created a computed property that returns my array and always when `this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn` updates, the array changes together (consequently the menu as well).

I intent to create a mapGetter to my `this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn`. As soon as I do it, I update the answer.

Thank you guys so much.

```js
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return { ... }
  },
  computed: {
    rightMenu () {
      return [
        { title: 'sign_in', to: '/sign_in', 
            showButton: !this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn },
        { title: 'sign_up', to: '/sign_up', 
            showButton: !this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn },
        { title: 'sign_out', to: '/sign_out',
            showButton: this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**EDIT 1: Solution using mapGetters**

**Menu.vue**

```js
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  data () {
    return { ... }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'isUserLoggedIn'
    ]),
    rightMenu () {
      return [
        { title: 'sign_in', to: '/sign_in', 
            showButton: !this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn },
        { title: 'sign_up', to: '/sign_up', 
            showButton: !this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn },
        { title: 'sign_out', to: '/sign_out',
            showButton: this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**store.js**

I've added the following getter:

```js
...
getters: {
  isUserLoggedIn (state) {
    return state.auth.isUserLoggedIn
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `computed` property to make it `reactive`:

```html
<template>
...
<v-btn v-for='item in rightMenu' :key='item.title'
  :to='item.to' v-if='isUserLoggedIn(item.title)' flat>
  {{ item.title }}
</v-btn>
...
</template>

<script>
...
computed: {
  isUserLoggedIn() {
    return (title) => {  // you'll not have any caching benefits
      if (title === 'sign out') {
        return this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn;
      }
      return !this.$store.state.auth.isUserLoggedIn;
    }
  }
}
...
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried to do these steps, but I got the following error: `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.isUserLoggedIn is not a function"`. Is it possible to pass a value in a computed property?

Comment: No, `computed` method does not take any parameter. Updated answer, can you try now?

Comment: I've tested your answer and it worked as well. Thank you so much.